# Getting INVALID , on Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I use [Quixotix-PHP-PayPal-IPN](https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN) Class, to get payments in my site.

The problem is that i always get INVALID from paypal, the code that i did is:

```
try {
    $verified = $listener->processIpn();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    file_put_contents('ipn_log.txt', $e);
    exit(0);
}

if ($verified) {
    file_put_contents('ipn_log.txt', 'success');
    if (strcasecmp($_POST['receiver_email'],$paymail) == 0 && $_POST['payment_status'] == 'Completed' && $_POST['mc_currency'] == 'USD')  {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT msg FROM prices WHERE price = ?') or die($db->error);
        $char = 'd';
        $stmt->bind_param($char, $_POST['payment_gross']);
        $stmt->execute() or die($db->error);
        $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            $stmt->bind_result($msg);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->close();
            $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE users SET pack = (pack + ?), transid = ? WHERE id = ? AND transid != ?') or die($db->error);
            $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
            $custom = $_POST['custom'];
            $stmt->bind_param('isis', $msg , $txn_id , $custom, $txn_id);
            $stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);
        }
    } 
}
else file_put_contents('ipn_log.txt', 'not verifed');
```

So i do a payment for checking, but the file 'ipn_log.txt' always contain: 'not verifed'

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the library hasn't been updated in a long time. There are many forks of it, that have been updated.

I also have a fork of it, fixed, and myself and others have used it in production: [WadeShuler/PHP-PayPal-IPN](https://github.com/WadeShuler/PHP-PayPal-IPN)

Switch to it, and see if that helps you. Please read the README and take a look at the example.